# XHR request stubbing for Capybara JavaScript Testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, rspec, capybara, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to write a `request_spec` that tests the functionality of a page with a form that does a ajax autocomplete lookup and returns valid results to then activate the submit button.

I'm wondering if anybody has has the same issue and found someway or references to get this test passing.

### Gemfile

```
gem 'rake', '0.8.7'
gem 'rails', '2.3.5'
group :test do
  gem "capybara", :git => "git://github.com/jnicklas/capybara.git"
  gem 'rspec', '1.3.1'
  gem 'rspec-core'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '1.3.2'
  gem 'webmock', '1.4.0'
end
```

### HTML

```
    ...
    <fieldset>
      <label>Enter a Destination</label>
      <%= text_field_tag :reviewable_name, nil, :id => "destination_autocomplete", :class => 'textfield'  %>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h3 class="disabled">
            <%= submit_tag "Read reviews", :id => "read_a_destination_review", :name => "agree", :class => "read_review", :disabled => false %>
          </h3>
        </li>
        <li class="or">or</li>
        <li>
          <h3>
            <%= submit_tag "Write review", :id => "write_a_destination_review", :name => "agree", :class => "write_review", :disabled => false %>
          </h3>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </fieldset>
    ...
```

### JavaScript (jQuery 1.4.4)

```
  ...
  $("#hotel_autocomplete, #destination_autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response){
      $.getJSON('/ajax/search_reviewable?type=destination&q=' + request.term,
        function(results, status){
          if(status == 'success'){
            //make it regex safe
            var term = request.term.replace(/([\^\$\(\)\[\]\{\}\*\.\+\?\|\\])/gi, "\\$1");
            term = term.split(' ').join('|');
            for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
              results[i].value = results[i].label;
              results[i].label = results[i].value.replace(new RegExp("("+term+")", "gi"),'<strong>$1</strong>');
            }
            response(results);
          }
        }
      );
    },
    minLength: 3,
    delay: 500,
    select: function( event, ui ) {...}
  });
  ...
```

### JSON Response

/ajax/search_reviewable?type=destination&q=florida

```
[{"label":"Florida","id":124}]
```

### RSpec Test

```
    it "should activate submit button", :js => true do
      stub_request(:get, "/ajax/search_reviewable/type=destination&q=florida").to_return(:body => %Q{[{"label":"Florida","id":124}]}, :headers => {"Content-Type" => "applicaation/json; charset=utf-8", "Accept" => "*/*"})
      fill_in("destination_autocomplete", :with => "florida")
      page.execute_script(%Q{$("#destination_autocomplete").trigger("keyup");})
      find(".ui-menu-item a").click
      # should post to '/review/new', :id => 124
      page.should have_content("Write a Destination Review")
    end
```

The test fails because this spec is unable to stub the XHR request within the JavaScript.

I thank you for your comments responses and help.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to find a solution to this issue.

What was actually happening, The AJAX requested page `/ajax/search_reviewable?type=destination&q=$1` was doing a Net::HTTP request to another service.

This request needed to be stubbed with the response I was needing.

```
stub_request(:get, ".../all_by_partial_name/Florida/").to_return({
  :body => %Q{[{"label":"Florida","id":124}]}, 
  :headers => {"Content-Type" => "applicaation/json; charset=utf-8", "Accept" => "*/*"}
})
```

After some major research, I found that you have to trigger a event in JavaScript to pass the test.

Source. [Clicking AutoComplete Options Gist](https://gist.github.com/508514#file_clicking_autocomplete_options.rb)

Now the spec example looks like this

```
before(:each) do
  stub_request(:get, ".../all_by_partial_name/Florida/").to_return({
    :body => %Q{[{"label":"Florida","id":124}]}, 
    :headers => {"Content-Type" => "applicaation/json; charset=utf-8", "Accept" => "*/*"}
  })
end

it "should activate submit button and direct to new review", :js => true do
  fill_in("destination_autocomplete", :with => "florida")
  sleep 2
  page.execute_script(%Q{$(".ui-menu-item a:eq(0)").trigger("mouseenter").click();})
  find_button("write_a_destination_review").click
  page.should have_content("Write a Destination Review")
end
```

I hope this helps you with resolving your RSpec JQuery issues.

Comment: For people who end up here from Google, it's worth noting that this requires the `webmock` gem, which disallows all real HTTP requests, so if your suite relies on real requests, this solution likely won't work for you.